# MySQL Error #1064 - I tried many options

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I tried adding a column at the end of the table by selecting the options in phpmyadmin but it throws me error. I copied the query and tried with SQL option in there by removing the quote & removing all the argument but it still gives error -

I tried -

```
ALTER TABLE `signup_event` ADD `payment_category` VARCHAR( 30 ) UNSIGNED NULL
    DEFAULT NULL AFTER `trans_status`;

ALTER TABLE signup_event ADD payment_category VARCHAR( 30 ) UNSIGNED NULL
    DEFAULT NULL AFTER trans_status;

ALTER TABLE signup_event ADD payment_category VARCHAR( 30 ) UNSIGNED NULL
    DEFAULT NULL AFTER trans_status

ALTER TABLE signup_event ADD payment_category VARCHAR( 30 ) UNSIGNED
    DEFAULT NULL AFTER trans_status;
```

Like this many times...

How to add a column in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `UNSIGNED` on varchar. `UNSIGNED` can only be used in numbers.

```
ALTER TABLE signup_event 
    ADD payment_category VARCHAR(30)  
    DEFAULT NULL AFTER trans_status;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/828ce/1)